# Converting text from first person to second person, and ignoring quotes

Tags: python, nltk

So I have this:

```
import nltk

forms = {"am" : "are", "are" : "am", 'i' : 'you', 'my' : 'yours', 'me' : 'you', 'mine' : 'yours', 'you' : 'I', 'your' : 'my', 'yours' : 'mine'} # More?
def translate(word):
  if word.lower() in forms: return forms[word.lower()]
  return word

sent = 'You went to see Avatar, and I came with you.'
result = ' '.join([translate(word) for word in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent)])
print(result.capitalize())
# I went to see avatar , and you came with i .
```

What do I add to prevent converting words within quotes " "

Example: example: 
input is:          'I go to the movies, I say "What do **you** want to see?" 
Conversion I want: 'You go to the movies, you say "What do **you** want to see?"
 Conversion I don't want: 'You go the movies, you say "what do **I** want to see?"

Comment: can you add an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Can you give an example of a scenario that has quotes? What does `word` look like in that case?

Comment: example: input is 'I go to the movies, I say "What do you want to see?"  Conversion I want: 'You go to the movies, you say "What do you want to see?"   Conversion I don't want: 'You go the movies, you say "what do I want to see?"

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a somewhat verbose script, but it should do the trick:

```py
sent = 'I go to the movies, I say "What do you want to see?"'

translated = []
quote_mode = False

for word in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent):
    if quote_mode:
        translated.append(word)
        if word == '"': quote_mode = False;

    if not quote_mode:
        translated.append(translate(word))
        if word == '"': quote_mode = True;

result = ' '.join(translated)
print(result.capitalize()) # You go to the movies, you say "What do you want to see?"
```

Basically, when the string enters "quote mode" the state is kept and words aren't translated. When the string exits out of the quotes, the words are translated.

Your original solution also put spaces between stop signs; that can be rectified with:

```py
result = result.replace(' "', '"')\
    .replace(' .', '.')\
    .replace(' ?', '?')\
    .replace(' ,', ',')
```

Comment: Thank you, the quote issue is solved. I now have an issue for the single quotes, such as this input: 'you realize it was 'her''   this causes a syntex error becuase of the single quotes interfering with each other. I am copy pasting stories to convert from first to third person, so i cannot fix every instance of this manually. same issues apply when making the input: "She says, "Wow!""

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that will let you ignore quotes:

```
def convertTxt(sent):
    quotes = [] #list of quote locations in txt
    qflag = False
    for c in range(len(sent)):
        if sent[c] == "\"":
            qflag = False if qflag else True
        if qflag:
            quotes.append(c) #record quote locations
    sentloc=0
    res = []
    result = ""
    for word in nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(sent):
        if sentloc in quotes:
            res.append(word) #exclude regions in quotes
        else:
            res.append(translate(word))
        sentloc += len(word) #keep track of sentence location
    for r in range(len(res)):
        if res[r].isalpha():
            if res[r-1][-1] not in "'\"" and (res[r-1][-1].isalpha() or res[r-1][-1] in ",."):
                result += " " + res[r]
            else:
                result += res[r]
        else:
            if res[r][0] not in ",'.?!" or res[r][0] == "\"":
                result += " " + res[r]
            else:
                result += res[r]
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you, the quote issue is solved. I now have an issue for the single quotes, such as this input: 'you realize it was 'her'' this causes a syntex error becuase of the single quotes interfering with each other. I am copy pasting stories to convert from first to third person, so i cannot fix every instance of this manually. same issues apply when making the input: "She says, "Wow!""